# opening .mdb files 2003 to ms access 2007

Tags: microsoft-access

I tried creating a test database from ms access 2003 and saved it as my Test.mdb.

Now, I would like to open it to ms access 2007 but when I do that I just get a box name "action failed"- Step is grayed out, Stop all macros, Continue (grayed-out). In the Box these are files: Macroname: AutoExec, Condition: True, Actionname: AusführenCode, Argument: InitApplication()

The Navigation Pane is not showed. At the top I'm seeing the Security warning - with the box of "Option".

I'm wondering what steps did I miss? and what's the problem why I can't open it normally. I've read that you can normally .mdb files to ms access 2007. But it seems it's not working in my case.

I'm using XP and also tried it to Vista and both showing the same results.

I appreciate any ideas

Cheers

==== 
Additional Info:

What I did is: I hold the shift button and then double clicked on the file Test.mdb it opened now to the ms access 2007. Where I can see my navigation pane at the left. Strange thing is I I activate the Makro at the top the navigation pane will be lost and toolbars as well. And the option I'll have left is the Databank Exit (end). Any idea what's happening?

=========

Additional Info:

Anybody is familiar with Charity Contributions Template with MS Access 2007?

Comment: As I replied on StackOverflow, you probably need to read up on Trusted Locations.

Comment: @David thanks I'll try this and will get back to you as soon as I finish it ok? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like your security levels are set to block macros, I'm not sure where it hides in 2007 but you need to set your macro security to medium before you open the mdb.

Comment: hmmm that's really quite strange. I installed something in my PC. The Access Runtime, Access DeveloperExtension,and AccessRunTimeAndConnectivity, then it started to open the file.

Comment: I guess maybe one of them changed the security for you, you're not likely to do development without macros

Comment: thanks Col. even my boss also don't know why it opened. Any idea about the template Charitable Contribution in Ms Access 2007?

Comment: Sorry can't help you there I don't have 2007 on this machine